# how do i edit stored connections in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

When I go to setup connection strings for LINQ to SQL data contexts, I see a list of established/already setup connections in a dropdown. how do I change the names of these connections? Is there a menu for managing established connections? how do i get there? I'm sure this is easy, I just literally don't know where to click or what to google.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Properties folder and the file Settings.settings

Comment: are these connections the same across all applications, or are they a feature of a particular solution?